# Using perl, given an array of any size, how do I randomly pick 1/4 of the list

Tags: perl

For clarification, if I had a list of 8 elements, i would want to randomly pick 2. If I had a list of 20 elements, I would want to randomly pick 5. I would also like to assure (though not needed) that two elements don't touch, i.e. if possible not the 3 and then 4 element. Rather, 3 and 5 would be nicer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution:

1. Shuffle the list
2. select the 1st quarter.

Example implementation:

```
use List::Util qw/shuffle/;
my @nums =  1..20;
my @pick = (shuffle @nums)[0 .. 0.25 * $#nums];
say "@pick";
```

Example output: `10 2 18 3 19`.

Your additional restriction “no neighboring numbers” actually makes this *less* random, and should be avoided if you want actual randomness. To avoid that two neighboring elements are included in the output, I would iteratively splice unwanted elements out of the list:

```
my @nums = 1..20;
my $size = 0.25 * @nums;
my @pick;
while (@pick < $size) {
  my $i = int rand @nums;
  push @pick, my $num = $nums[$i];
  # check and remove neighbours
  my $len = 1;
  $len++       if $i < $#nums and $num + 1 == $nums[$i + 1];
  $len++, $i-- if 0  < $i     and $num - 1 == $nums[$i - 1];
  splice @nums, $i, $len;
}
say "@pick";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub randsel {
    my ($fact, $i, @r) = (1.0, 0); 
    while (@r * 4 < @_) {
        if (not grep { $_ == $i } @r) {
            $fact = 1.0;
            # make $fact = 0.0 if you really don't want
            # consecutive elements
            $fact = 0.1 if grep { abs($i - $_) == 1 } @r; 
            push(@r, $i) if (rand() < 0.25 * $fact);
        }
        $i = ($i + 1) % @_; 
    }   
    return map { $_[$_] } sort { $a <=> $b } @r; 
}

my @l; 
$l[$_] = $_ for (0..19);
print join(" ", randsel(@l)), "\n";
```